# how to use \n in a print function with argument

Tags: python-3.x

i cant seem to get the right syntax that will make me:

Using one of the comparison operators in Python, write a simple two-line program that takes the parameter n as input, which is an integer, and prints False if n is less than 100, and True if n is greater than or equal to 100.

Don't create any if blocks (we're going to talk about them very soon). Test your code using the data we've provided for you.

here is what i tried:

```
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
print (2 * n < 100 \n 2 * n >= 100)
```

Comment: What data have they provided for you?

Comment: 55....i used 55, i think i cant just make the \n work such that i wont have to type a 3 lines of code

Comment: The problem is likely "print False if n is less than 100, ***or*** print True if n is greater than or equal to 100." However, if you want to print both, just use `print(2*n<100,'\n',2*n>=100)`.

Comment: @jpf, I'm going to go all CDO(see footnote A) here and state that `and` is also correct. You (print false if n < 100) ***and*** (print true if n >= 100). You can actually do *both* those things but, being mutually exclusive and both halves doing nothing if their respective conditions are false means that there's no functional difference with `or`. Footnote A: OCD, but in the correct damn order :-)

Comment: @jpf ,  print(2*n<100,'\n',2*n>=100) solved the problem...thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @paxdiablo Agreed. I was lazy in trying to suggest that perhaps printing both results was not expected in the problem statement. To validate your OCD, the original problem would then be "(print False if n < 100; otherwise print True) AND (print True if n>=100; otherwise print False)"

Comment: @OlaotanHamid: I'm still not clear why you're multiplying the value by two when there's *nothing* in your provided description that requests this. In addition, your proposed code prints *two* values, either false/true or true/false, despite the fact the text asked for you to print either true *or* false. I think you may want to read that text a little more closely.

Comment: thanks for the observation, there is a sample input of n=55 and it also ask(or i was trying to) that both instances be outputted; when its < & >= 100.

Answer (score 1):

Not *entirely* certain what you hope to achieve with:

```
print (2 * n < 100 \n 2 * n >= 100)
```

I suspect you think you need both sub-parts to print either true or false but I'm not sure why you would multiply by two, nor why you have a "naked" newline sequence, something that's usually just found inside strings.

It *may* be that you've misinterpreted `a simple two-line program` to mean two lines of *output* rather than two lines in your actual program (the `input` statement and the `print` statement).

In any case, you can print `True/False` with just the statement:

```
print(n >= 100)
```

If it's less that a hundred, that expression will be false so will print `False`. Otherwise, the expression will be true and it will print `True`. Nothing really earth-shattering there :-)

See the following transcript for an example:

```
>>> n = 55 ; print(n >= 100)
False
>>> n = 98 ; print(n >= 100)
False
>>> n = 99 ; print(n >= 100)
False
>>> n = 100 ; print(n >= 100)
True
>>> n = 101 ; print(n >= 100)
True
```

---

Bottom line, your two lines of code should be something like (you already *have* the first one):

```
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
print(n >= 100)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i want to write just two lines of code that will print false if n is less than 100 and also true if n is greater than or equal to 100. given that n = 55.

Comment: @OlaotanHamid, I've added a very explicit section to the end of the answer just for clarity. Don't get hung up on the "and" in the question (or the "and also" in your previous comment here). Because `<100` and `>=100` are mutually exclusive, you can only ever do *one* of the actions, so the `print(n >= 100)` is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Keep short and simple.

```
n = int(input("Put n Value :"))
print(n >= 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

It asks for a 2 lines python code.
Taking an input (which returns a string) and converting to an integer then you put the result in a variable named n.
Finally, if you write `n >= 100` it returns `True` if `n >= 100` otherwise `False`. In python you can print booleans that way.

```
n = int(input("Enter a value for n:"))
print(n >= 100)
```

We could separate the "input" and "integer convesion" into different lines but it would have more lines than the max established (would have 3 lines).

Note:
You could just do a one-liner by simply doing:

```
print(int(input("Enter a value for n:")) >= 100)
```